# can I declare a dynamic array of struct references within a struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct, segmentation-fault

Basically I am trying to build a hash structure of cstrings that I can re-assign the member `stringnode_ref *nodes` to a larger dimension array (malloc a new one, re-hash the existing values, and delete the old one) when the hash begins to fill up.

stringtable.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stringtable.h"

struct stringnode{
    hashcode_t key;
    cstring value;
};

struct stringtable{
    size_t dim;
    size_t numEntries;
    stringnode_ref *nodes;
};

stringtable_ref new_stringtable(){
    size_t index = 0;
    stringtable_ref sTable = malloc(sizeof(struct stringtable));
    sTable->dim = 31;
    sTable->numEntries;
    sTable->nodes = malloc(31 * sizeof(struct stringnode));
    for( index = 0; index < 31; index++ ){
        sTable->nodes[index]->key = 0;
        sTable->nodes[index]->value = NULL;
    }
    return sTable;
}
```

stringtable.h:

```
#ifndef __STRINGTABLE_H__
#define __STRINGTABLE_H__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef char *cstring;

typedef uint32_t hashcode_t;

typedef stringtable *stringtable_ref;

typedef stringnode *stringnode_ref;

stringtable_ref new_stringtable();

#endif // __STRINGTABLE_H__
```

oc.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stringtable.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    stringtable_ref table = new_stringtable();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compiling with:

```
gcc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -c stringtable.c
gcc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -c oc.c
gcc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -o oc stringtable.o oc.o
```

this all compiles fine with no errors but upon declaring `stringtable_ref table = new_stringtable();` in the main(), the program segfaults at `sTable->nodes[index]->key = 0;`. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to allocate memory and have it referenced by `sTable->nodes`, just as you do for `sTable` itself.

Comment: Im getting compilation error. `error: unknown type name ‘stringtable’`. i.e `stringtable` and `stringnode` is unknown during typedef.

Comment: The types' names are `struct stringtable` and `struct stringnode`.

Comment: I cannot compile this code. What compiler and what options are you using? What is hashcode_t?

Comment: @January Neither could I - but I figured out this error. You have to typedef `hashcode_t` (perhaps `unsigned long`?) and fix the borken typedefs in the first lines by adding the `struct` keyword.

Comment: this is actually copy pasted from 3 different files. I will edit

Comment: Hello, this new code does not compile either, not with gcc.

Comment: "Any thoughts?" -- The usual one ... **use a debugger**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sTable->nodes = malloc(31 * sizeof(struct stringnode));
for( index = 0; index < 31; index++ ){
    sTable->nodes[index]->key = 0;
```

here's the problem: the segfault occurs because you don't allocate memory for `sTable-nodes[index]`, so it may be garbage (when I examined your code on GDB under OS X, it was actually `NULL`).

Solution: add the following line as the first line of the body of the `for` loop:

```
sTable->nodes[index] = malloc(sizeof(*(sTable->nodes[index])));
```

Comment: Sidenote: as perhaps @bdonlan pointed out, there may be (and I suspect there are) other errors as well in your code, but this was the first one I could quickly spot and this fixed it for now. However, you **still have to go through your entire code using GDB** and your eyes also, after having understood pointers and constrained yourself to use the `sizeof()` operator correctly.

Comment: However, `sTable->nodes = malloc(31 * sizeof(struct stringnode));` is still incorrect, because `sTable->nodes` is a pointer to `stringnode_ref`, and not a pointer to `struct stringnode`.

Comment: @January I think you missed my previous comment.

Comment: No, I haven't missed that, and I agree with you, I'm just pointing out to a specific problem. `sizeof( struct stringnode )` may be ugly and not recommended and thus treated as incorrect, but in itself it is not an error. However, it indicates that the intent of the programmer was different and that the problem lies with the defining `nodes` as `stringnode_ref *` rather than `struct stringnode *` or `stringnode_ref`.

Comment: now that you pointed it out, it makes sense that I not only needed to declare `sTable->nodes = malloc sizeof( 31 * sizeof( *sTable->nodes );` but also that only creates an array of `stringnode_ref`'s. meaning for each `stringnode_ref` in the array, I am still required to `malloc( sizeof( *sTable->nodes[index] ));` Thanks you very much.

Comment: @January You misunderstood me :) I do encourage the use of `sizeof(*variable)` instead of `sizeof(type)` because the latter will break when the type of a variable changes.

Comment: @H2CO3: oh god, this internet discussions, we would solve this misunderstandings in ten seconds flat in RL :-). (i) I completely agree with you and encouraging use of `sizeof(*variable)`, see my answer below; (ii) I was referring to another problem of which the incorrect `sizeof()` was but a sign.

Comment: "I encourage the use of `sizeof(*variable)`" -- but you actually wrote `sizeof(*(variable))`. Myself, I encourage `sizeof *variable`, with *neither* set of extraneous parens. And a justification for that, in addition to readability, is as a reminder that `sizeof` is a keyword, not a function.

Comment: @jim balter I know it's not a function. In my answer, I wrote the parentheses because I wanted to make sure the * operator is applied to the correct term - it's not always obvious for everyone reading the answer at first glance. In general, I rather try to avoid complex and obscurely-chained variable combinations and just write `sizeof (*variable)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You define the `nodes` element of  `stringtable` as a pointer to `stringnode_ref`, that is, as a pointer to pointer to `struct stringnode`. Since you do `sTable->nodes = malloc(31 * sizeof(struct stringnode));`, you calculate the size of `sTable->nodes` as if it was pointer to `struct stringnode` (which it isn't).

Possibly, you want to define stringtable like this:

```
struct stringtable{
  size_t dim;
  size_t numEntries;
  stringnode_ref nodes;
};
```

You can then initialize the nodes using

```
sTable->nodes[index].key = 0;
sTable->nodes[index].value = NULL;
```

Here is the whole code that compiles correctly and does not show memory errors with valgrind. Compilation with `gcc -Wall --pedantic -o ttt -g ttt.c`; checking for memory errors with `valgrind --tool=memcheck  ./ttt`. Please note how `sizeof()` is used and implement it in your own code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char *cstring;

struct stringnode{
    int key;
    cstring value;
};

typedef struct stringnode *stringnode_ref;

struct stringtable{
    size_t dim;
    size_t numEntries;
    stringnode_ref nodes;
};

typedef struct stringtable *stringtable_ref;

stringtable_ref new_stringtable(){
    size_t index = 0;
    stringtable_ref sTable = malloc(sizeof( *sTable ) ) ;
    sTable->dim = 31;
    sTable->nodes = malloc(31 * sizeof( *sTable->nodes ) ) ;
    for( index = 0; index < 31; index++ ){
        sTable->nodes[index].key = 0;
        sTable->nodes[index].value = NULL;
    }
    return sTable;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  stringtable_ref table = new_stringtable();
  exit( EXIT_SUCCESS ) ;
}
```

P.S. The attempt to compile the code as you have described in your edited post results in the following:

```
:~/tmp$ gcc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -c stringtable.c
In file included from stringtable.c:2:
stringtable.h:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
stringtable.h:13: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
stringtable.h:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘new_stringtable’
stringtable.c:12: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘stringnode_ref’
stringtable.c:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘new_stringtable’
```

Comment: I chose the other answer because it more addressed the specific issue of why I was segfaulting. But thank you for showing me how `sizeof()` is intended to be used.